# Error using IntelliJ ultimate " Method Call Expected"

Tags: java, class, methods, access-modifiers

This method is in my parent class it is named "getEasterAttack" I am trying to call it in another class that is ninjaGetDamageRecieved how ever the error "Method Call Expected" keeps coming up. Is it because the receives in my method signature is not asking for an int? or is it because of my access modifiers? Thanks for the help

```
public  int getEasterAttack() {
    int shark = 100;
    int randnum = RandInt.randomInt(0, 125);

    if (randnum == getHealth()) {

    }
    return shark;
public int ninjaDamageReceivedCalculator(int rawDamageDealt) {
    int damage = 0;
    int protection = 0;
    if (getPlayerWeapon().equalsIgnoreCase("blade")) {
        damage = rawDamageDealt - (getRandomBladeRangeProtection() * getRandomAccuracyDamage());
    } else {
        damage = rawDamageDealt - (getRandomStarRangeProtection() * getRandomAccuracyDamage());
    }
    if (rawDamageDealt > protection + getForestProtection()) {
        damage = rawDamageDealt - (protection + getForestProtection());
    }
    this.removeHealth(damage);
    return damage(getEasterAttack());
}
```

Comment: So your *class* is named *getEasterAttack*? And another class is called *ninjaDamangeReceivedCalculate*? That's invalid in your use case

Comment: What do you expect `damage(getEasterAttack())` to do?

Comment: You can start by closing the bracket for the `getEasterAttack` function

Comment: I have since realized my terminology was not correct with my use of Class instead of Method. First I made an Alternative class of with getEasterAttack it  then instantiated it into my NVA class that has my ninjaDamangeReceivedCalculater. Thanks for the attempt at making sense of my nonsense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`damage` is not a method but a `int` value. Therefore Intellij warns you that using it as a method won't work:

`damage(getEasterAttack())` is not possible for `int`.